# How to Customize View Output

Tags: views, theming

I'm working on some views and I came across a requirement I'm not sure how to handle.

I need the title for each returned item to link to a specific URL. However, if another field (a link field) isn't empty, link to that link instead. I believe I need to edit the view template files but I'm not sure how to get started.

- In my view, I've found the "Theme: Information" section and am able to get template files working for my view. However, it's listing display, style, row, and field templates. Where would I incorporate the logic I described above for the title field?
- Once in a template file I am unsure of what variables are available to me. Is there a list or a way to discover these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views is rendered by some of *.tpl.php files, they are:

- views-view.tpl.php. Main view template.
- views-view-unformatted.tpl.php. Default simple view template to display a list of rows.
- [views-view-fields.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!views-view-fields.tpl.php/7). Default simple view template to all the fields as a row.
- views.view-field.tpl.php. This template is used to print a single field in a view.

If you want to use two different fields from one view in one file, I recommend to use `views-view-fields.tpl.php` where you can manipulate of all fields which you assign to view.

The `views-view-fields.tpl.php` has three variables to use: `$view`, `$fields` and `$row`. I suggest to use only `$fields`.

Then, if you have field named `field_image` you can render its using `$fields['field_image']->content` or `$fields['field_image']->raw`.

Also, I recommend to read more about it: [Views template files](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme%21theme.inc/group/views_templates/7)

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I've created a tpl file names something similar to views-view-fields--page-topic.tpl.php and it is affecting the correct content on the site. However, I've looked around in the $fields var and all the content is already rendered as HTML in $fields['field_lede']->content. I don't have individual pieces of content. Do you know what might cause that?

Comment: Fields in `view-views-fields.tpl-php` still are rendered by Views UI module. Thats why I mentioned about `$fields['field_name']->raw`. Also in Views UI you have to set that link generated by Link module is plain URL.